# <table> ending <div> tags

Tags: php, html, css

I'm losing the will here!

I've been trying to nest a simple table into a div, it all looks fine in the source code, but when I open page source in the browser, it is completely different!
Here's a snippet of the source:

```
<div class='floatl' style='width: 50%;'>
  <div class='contenthead'>50/50 Cash</div>
  <div class='contentcontent'>
    <table>
      <?
        $lookupcash = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `5050_cash`");
        while($line = mysql_fetch_array($lookupcash)){
          $better = new User($line['user']);
          echo "<tr>
            <td>".$better->formattedname."</td>
            <td>$".prettynum($line['amount'])."</td>
            <td><form method='post'>
              <input type='hidden' name='bet_id' value='".$line['id']."' />
              <input type='submit' name='take_cash' value='Take Bet' />
            </form></td>
          </tr>";
        }           
      ?>            
    </table>
    <form method='post'>
      <p>Wager: $ <input type='number' min='10000' max='1000000' step='10000' value='10000' name='cash' /></p>
      <span style='font-size:11px;color:#999;'>Minimum wager: $10,000</span><br />
      <p style='padding: 1px;'>Confirm: <input type='submit' name='post_cash' value='Place Bet' /></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot to how it appears in chromes inspect element (and consequently, how it is rendered on the webpage):

[image]

Comment: Do you have a demo link? Can you post the parsed HTML please?

Comment: run the page through the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/). Having blocks of markup "jump" positions like that is usually a sign of broken markup elsewhere in the document. the validator'll show you where the bugs are.

Comment: Did you try `style = 'display:table'`

Comment: Without seeing the actual HTML output, and/or the secret PHP STUFF, it's tough to guess what's happening here.

Comment: Full source for the problemed <div> has been added

Comment: Is there any relevant css for contentcontent?

Comment: `.contentcontent {
    margin: 0;
    padding:-5px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    padding: 6px;
    color: #DDD;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}`

Comment: How does it look in VIEW SOURCE? Note the VIEW SOURCE Is the source code coming from the server. The CODE INSPECTOR is the code after any DOM manipulations.

Comment: and the CSS will have nothing to do with an HTML nesting issue. Odds are you have invalid markup elsewhere on the page and it's manifesting itself here.

Comment: Page source does indeed come through as desired, I will check the rest of the source to see if there has been an unclosed tag somewhere along the line

Comment: You're absolutely right, each page includes a header & footer with it, at the end of the header file is <table> and footer starts with </table>

Answer (score 0):

Does this work ?

```
echo "<table><tr><td>".$variable."</td><td>$".$variable."</td>
    <td><form method='post'><input type='hidden' name='bet_id' value='".$variable."' /><input type='submit' name='take_cash' value='Take Bet' /></form></td></tr></table>";
    }
```

Comment: The echo is within a while() loop, so the table tag needs to be outside of it

Comment: But no, it doesn't, still causes the containing <div> to close!

Answer (score 0):

See the attached code and screenshot of rendered output. The only thing that differs from my code and yours is a) the css (maybe a mixing on inline and block level elements?) b) your database records and custom functions, and maybe c) the browser version. I would look there for an answer. This is what I see on Chrome version 31 and latest Firefox on Mac, which I assume is what you're going for.

```
<div class='floatl' style='width: 50%;'>
<div class='contenthead'>50/50 Cash</div>
<div class='contentcontent'><table>
<?
    $i = 0;

    while($i < 10){
    echo "<tr><td>turtle</td><td>$monnnnnnaay</td>
    <td><form method='post'><input type='hidden' name='bet_id' value='snapple' /><input type='submit' name='take_cash' value='Take Bet' /></form></td></tr>";
    $i++;
    }

?>          
</table>

<form method='post'>
    <p>Wager: $ <input type='number' min='10000' max='1000000' step='10000' value='10000' name='cash' /></p>
    <span style='font-size:11px;color:#999;'>Minimum wager: $10,000</span><br />
    <p style='padding: 1px;'>Confirm: <input type='submit' name='post_cash' value='Place Bet' /></p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]